# Why is XCTest with a predicate based expectation so slow?

Tags: objective-c, swift, performance, nspredicate, xctest

Anybody know why XCTest expectations with predicates are so slow? It appears to me that the minimum execution time for both Swift and ObjC is 1 second even if the predicate should pass immediately. Wrapping my expectations with an `if !pred.evaluate(with:obj)` sped up test execution by several orders of magnitude.

```
import XCTest

struct TestObject {
  var value = true
}

class SwiftPredicateTestTests: XCTestCase {
  func testPerformanceExample() {
    let obj = TestObject()
    self.measure {
      let pred = NSPredicate{(evaluatedObject, _) in
        return (evaluatedObject as! TestObject).value
      }
      let expect = expectation(for: pred, evaluatedWith: obj, handler: nil)
      wait(for: [expect], timeout: 30)
    }
  }
}
```

```
measured [Time, seconds] average: 1.013, relative standard deviation: 2.464%, values: [1.087598, 1.002806, 1.003474, 1.001123, 1.004604, 1.007821, 1.004224, 1.005046, 1.005243, 1.007546],
```

Comment: Filed with Apple as FB7657125

Answer (score 1):

This effect is also noticeable in `waitForExistence` method. 
They probably use `sleep(1)` before condition checking in cycles.

Comment: I noticed it when I added it to the teardown for some tests and all 200 of them started taking a second each as opposed to a small fraction of a second previously.